# XCode 7.1 Testflight Internal Testing bug

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, testflight, application-loader

I have spent the entire day trying to fix what I do believe by now it is a bug from Apple'e end.

I have successfully uploaded an iOS build to iTC which has been properly processed and states 'testing' under the internal testing tab of the TestFlight section.

I tried switching Internal Testing on/off in vain (always gives 'operation_failed'). I also tried to remove and re-add internal testers.

No invites sent. Nothing on TestFlight. What the hell is going on?

Note that this isn't the first build I submit for internal testing. Others used to work normally (Back in XCode 7.0 and the older version of iTC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That same issue also faced by me.

**Solution:**

If you have migrated from XCode 6.x to XCode 7.x, then that issue might have faced. new Xcode default setting is disable to testing functionality. so have to enable it again.

Xcode 7.x gives you suggestion to enable it in left-side "Project Warnings" area.

Look into it if you find any warning like **"Update to recommended settings"**, select it, it will open popup, press "Perform Changes" and again send new build to Test Flight and wait for time (may take 1 or 2 hours sometime).

And its done!!!

You will get your tester list in Test Flight new submitted build. :)

**You can also Enable it from:
Xcode > Target > Build Settings > Build Options > Enable Testability > Make "Yes" for debug.**